# Awards, grants and fellowships for PhD students in TCS

Tags: soft-question, career

I think that a PhD student that received some awards and fellowships has better chance to get a good postdoc position. I was wondering what awards/grants/fellowships should one consider to apply for?

Here are three that I know of:

- [Microsoft Research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/academic-program/phd-fellowship-program/)
- [IBM](http://www.research.ibm.com/university/awards/phdfellowship.shtml)
- Simons Foundation. Although this one seems obsolete.

I'm mostly interested in grants and awards in the US, but I think it's good to have an international list here too.

Comment: In the US, NSF GRFP & NDSEG are the big federal fellowship programs for science PhD students.

Comment: NSERC in Canada. Only for Canadians, though.

Comment: Maybe worth making the distinction, in the answers, between "grants and awards in the US *for which only US citizens qualify*" and "grants and awards in the US."